# Alternative sources of potassium to the banana?

Tags: food, recovery, muscle-soreness

I have started working out recently and my muscles hurt to say the least. I heard potassium helps with that and that bananas are a good source of it. The thing is that I hate the taste of bananas. Is there a natural source of that out there in another fruit or vegetable, or is my only option to take potassium in pill form?

Comment: Can you share any insight (i.e. references/urls) on the link between potassium and muscle soreness?

Comment: http://www.lifesource4life.com/conditions/c-muscle.htm

"Nutritional deficiencies of calcium, magnesium, potassium, and the B vitamins are often the root cause of muscle aches and cramps."

Comment: Nutrition questions are off topic according to the [FAQ].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=nutrient&dbid=90:

> What foods provide potassium?
>
> Potassium is found in abundance in
>   many foods, and is especially easy to
>   obtain in fruits and vegetables.
>   Excellent sources of potassium include
>   chard, crimini mushrooms, and spinach.
>
> Very good sources of potassium include
>   fennel, kale, mustard greens, Brussel
>   sprouts, broccoli, winter squash,
>   blackstrap molasses, eggplant,
>   cantaloupe, and tomatoes.
>
> Good sources of potassium include
>   parsley, cucumber, bell pepper,
>   turmeric, apricots, ginger root,
>   strawberries, avocado, banana, tuna,
>   halibut, cauliflower and cabbage.

Comment: I love me some spinach.

Comment: There's also a fair amount in celery, I believe.

Comment: Coconut water is an excellant source of Potassium.

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of [potassium in bananas](http://www.calories-in-foods.com/calories-in-banana.php), a large 136 g banana contains 477 mg of potassium, which is pretty good. As far as workouts go the banana is great to eat before, during and after, they are small and can be eaten on their own, where as several other high potassium foods need to be part of a meal.

But obviously if you don't like the taste then looking elsewhere at one of the other many [foods that contain potassium](http://www.calories-in-foods.com/foods-high-potassium.php) is a good plan. How about prunes or prune juice, pumpkin seeds, or raisins which are a great source of potassium?

You could take potassium supplements BUT you have to consider that this is just one nutrients that you will get from them, whereby any foods are going to have a wealth of other nutritional benefits on top of the potassium, plus fruits like raisins also have natural sugars that will provide you with the energy you need when working out.